# Is it possible to have a where clause reference another where clause in a Union All BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm playing around with BQ SQL and was wondering if it was possible to have a single `WHERE` clause within an entire `UNION ALL` statement. So instead of having multiple different `WHERE` clauses and having to change all of them in order to run a single query, to instead have it all linked to a single `WHERE` clause where everything would change based off that single change. I have dummy data below as an example of what I'm doing now:

```
 WITH Temp_A AS(
   SELECT DISTINCT
     Name,
     Date,
     Spend
   FROM
     Spend_Table
),
Temp_B AS(
   SELECT DISTINCT
     Name,
     Date,
     Revenue
   FROM
     Revenue_Table
),
Temp_C AS(
   SELECT DISTINCT
     Employee AS Name,
     Date,
     Paystub_Range,
     Hourly,
     Total_Amount
   FROM
     Employee_Pay
)
SELECT DISTINCT
   a.Name,
   a.Date,
   a.Spend,
   b.Revenue,
   NULL AS Paystub_Range,
   NULL AS Hourly,
   NULL AS Total_Amount
FROM
   Temp_A a

LEFT JOIN
   Temp_B b
ON
   a.Name = b.Name
   AND a.Date = b.Date

WHERE
   DATE BETWEEN '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-15'

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT
  Name,
  Date,
  NULL AS Spend,
  NULL AS Revenue,
  Paystub_Range,
  Hourly,
  Total_Amount
FROM
  Temp_C

WHERE
   DATE BETWEEN '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-15'
```

What I want to accomplish or see if it is possible is the same concept of the `WITH AS` data but have a single `WHERE` statement or have the second `WHERE` statement reference the first. So For example below same kind of dummy data as above, just doing the `SELECT DISTINCT` final version. Same Temp tables/etc.

```
)

SELECT DISTINCT
   a.Name,
   a.Date,
   a.Spend,
   b.Revenue,
   NULL AS Paystub_Range,
   NULL AS Hourly,
   NULL AS Total_Amount
FROM
   Temp_A a

LEFT JOIN
   Temp_B b
ON
   a.Name = b.Name
   AND a.Date = b.Date

WHERE
   DATE BETWEEN '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-15'

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT
  Name,
  Date,
  NULL AS Spend,
  NULL AS Revenue,
  Paystub_Range,
  Hourly,
  Total_Amount
FROM
  Temp_C

WHERE
   DATE BETWEEN @DateA AND @DateB
```

Or is there another way of doing this that I'm overlooking that would make this simpler? Any help would be much appreciated as I'm still learning everything I can about this to make it easier in the long run. Please let me know if I need to expand on any details, again this is just dummy data.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways: (1) scripting variables and (2) parameterized queries.

(1) scripting variables - declare variables and then use them in query

```
DECLARE from_date DATE DEFAULT '2020-09-01';
DECLARE to_date DATE DEFAULT '2020-09-15';

...your query...
WHERE DATE BETWEEN from_date AND to_date 
...rest of the query...
```

(2) parameterized queries - is not supported on BigQuery UI but on BQ CLI and Client Library you can use them.

For example, if using BQ CLI, you can do something like this:

```
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--parameter='from_date:DATE:2020-09-01' \
--parameter='to_date:DATE:2020-09-15' \
'SELECT
...your query...
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date 
...rest of the query...'
```